# Time delay in lumped element delay line

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, transmission-line, electromagnetic

I was trying to analyse a lumped element-delay line by changing the frequency and measuring \$ V_{in}\$ , as shown in the graph the goal of my analysis is to find the time-delay and the attenuation for the circuit thus finding, the capacitance and inductance for the circuit shown below  [image: lumped element delay line]

The problem that I am currently facing is I can't relate the time delay, nor the attenuation with the frequency, and the measured \$ V_{in}\$. I have an equation that relate the coefficient of the reflection and propagation waves. as follow

$$V_n=A(e^{i(\omega t-n\phi)}+re^{i(\omega t+n\phi)}$$

where \$ \omega=2\pi f\$, \$n\$ is the voltage in the \$n^{th}\$ section \$ \phi\$ is the phase change per section.

I obtained results for different terminal impedance, namely resistance equal to infinity, zero, and other value for resistance. Any help in how what should I do from here to find attenuation will be appreciated.

[[image: <span class=]\$ V_{in}\$ is a function of frequency" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Ozp.png)

Comment: try measuring the phase of Vout with respect to Vin

Comment: I tried to measure that, but the main problem that I am facing is that the x-axis is measured by frequency, not time.